# How to add the librealsense2 to Qt creator?

Tags: qt, opencv, realsense

I'm pretty new with OpenCV & Intel Realsense device. I don't know how to add the librealsense2 to Qt creator. I searched many ways but they are not working for me.
I have no idea how to make it. So anybody has any hint??

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure about that you properly installed librealsense. You can check [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/distribution_linux.md) to install.

After installation is done, you should add `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS` to `.pro` file. You didn't tell which operating system you are using. If its ubuntu, you can add simply like:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/librealsense2
LIBS += -L$$DESTDIR/ -lrealsense2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I use Cmake to bulid the project, not use Qmake. So how I can add the lib to CMakelist.txt?